# htaccess to redirect GET vars without touching css links

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, get

Well, I've read pages and more pages of htaccess guides and questions here at stackoverflow, but *still* I haven't found an answer to this problem.

I want the URL www.domain.com/profile/1 to be redirected to www.domain.com/profile.php?id=1, and the sabe to www.domain.com/profile/ranisalt to be redirected to www.domain.com/profile.php?seo=ranisalt

I'm using this rewrite rules and it have been working nice at **redirecting**:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/ profile.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
(there is more, but not relevant)
```

The problem is, the CSS is in the folder css/, if I access directly by profile.php?id=1 it loads correctly (www.domain.com/css/style.css), but when I access the mask, it tries to find css at www.domain.com/profile/1/css/style.css, which is not found.

I've been using this as a temporary fix

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(css|js)/(.*).(css|js)$ css/$3.$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/img/(.*).(jpg|png)$ img/$2.$3 [L]
```

But it doesn't look neat and nice :(

How can I make it load CSS nicely and correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You relative URI base has changed, so when the browser loads a URL like `www.domain.com/profile/ranisalt`, relative links to stuff like css will get `/profile/` appended to the front of the URI (thus reslving to `www.domain.com/profile/css/some.css`). In the HTML generated by `profile.php`, you need to add a URI base by adding this tag to the page's header:

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: It didn't change anything, it is still trying to find /profile/css/(...)